# Is creating a docker container effectively offering a guarantee that some program can be run long in the future (let us say 25 years)?

Tags: archive

Let's say I have a program, quite complex, relying on many packages / dependencies, and I want to make sure that I will still be able to run it all in 25 years from now.

Is docker (or similar) containerization a way to (realistically) allow this? Or is this outside of the scope of what a docker container offers?

If this sort of containerization is not the way to go, any other suggestion?

*Note:*

If you believe that this question is outside of the scope of Stackoverflow, please feel free to comment about it and I will remove it. In this case, any suggestion of where I could post it?

Comment: Will you still be able to run *Docker* in 25 years, and will it still read the same Docker container format then…? In the end you need to package *that* as well if you want to have that guarantee. Together with an OS to run it on. And hardware to run the OS on…

Comment: I guess there will still be some hardware and OS able to run a form of linux in a flavor or another. Taking Singularity, it is free and open source, so I guess if people still use it it will be still available? But anyways this is digressing - the question is rather (maybe I should reformulate), is using a container the right tool for the job here?

Comment: And the answer is basically in what I said above: the container won't "degrade" and won't depend on anything external, you can be pretty assured of that. But you need certain software to run the container, and whether *that* is still available in 25 years is impossible to know. The only way to be *sure* of that is to keep a current version of Docker around that is known to be able to execute the container; and to be able to ensure you can still run Docker, you archive the currently known good OS version… and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version out EVERYTHING, OS, Docker Img, any dependency and in theory, yes you can build something that will last 25 years if you satisfy all those things that require your docker image to work, disabling automated updates if any of those dependencies might be helpful and not recommended but it will fulfill the task of working out for 25 years.

Build a REALLY STRONG Documentation about your docker image, unless it's going to be a nightmare to do maintance for future developers and best of luck my friend, I don't recommend you doing this tbh

A quick example is DOOM, you can run it almost everywhere, certainly there might be a way be a way to make your docker image work after 25 years